# How to set style style on Shopify EASDK modal.confirm

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

This appears to have stopped working since Shopify released the "app bridge".

My modal code is this (*[straight from docs](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/embedded-apps/embedded-app-sdk/methods#shopifyapp-modal-confirm-options-fn)*):

```
    ShopifyApp.Modal.confirm({
      title: "Delete your account?",
      message: "Do you want to delete your account? This can't be undone.",
      okButton: "Yes, delete my account",
      cancelButton: "No, keep my account"
    }, function(result){
      alert("The modal was closed.");
    });
```

The docs say this:

> All modal dialogs can also accept a style: 'danger' attribute which
>   will change the primary button from blue to red, useful for delete
>   confirmations.

This is what appears:
[image]

As you can see, I have no `style` attribute included in my code, however, the modal is still styled with the red button (which should be only for the danger style). *Try the other `disabled` style attribute also does nothing.*

**Is this broken now? Or is there new undocumented ways to set this?**

Comment: I think you are supposed to use App Bridge. The old EASDK is being retired. So there are probably changes in ShopifyApp that affect everything like Modals. Everything Shopify is touching right now with Polaris, EASDK and Bridge is in flux, changing and not well documented. As you probably know.

Comment: Thanks David, it said there was supposed to be a backwards compatible layer in place, but I guess some things don't make it through.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. As you can tell, so much change is happening, and they admit that the whole introduction of the Bridge was made without really testing what would happen with it. Turned out to be a little awkward at best as they say...

Comment: Hey @coler-j did you ever get this fixed up? Having the exact same issue.

Comment: No I think it is a bug. I reported it but I dont think that went anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was discovered to be a bug with our Legacy Bridge, a compatibility layer that powers EASDK apps now that App Bridge is the default, and a fix has been applied. It will be deploying shortly. I apologize on behalf of the App Bridge team for the inconvenience this might have caused you.

Andrew

App Bridge (iOS Mobile)